# I want to get count of ID with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT (select statename from state where stateid = cpownerstate) as cpownerstate,
       count(cpownerid) 
  FROM cpownerdetail 
 where cpownerhashcode=0 
 group by cpownerstate;

SELECT (select statename from state where stateid = cpownerstate) as cpownerstate,
       count(cpownerid) 
  FROM cpownerdetail
 where cpownerhashcode!=0
 group by cpownerstate;
```

This is correct query but I want it in single query how it is possible

**sample table**:

[image]

Comment: Use `sum(cpownerhashcode = 0)` and `sum(cpownerhashcode <> 0)`

Comment: You can use `union all` or `group by cpownerstate, (cpownerhashcode=0);`

Comment: you want cpownerhashcode=0 and cpownerhashcode!=0 in a single result set?
use ORDER BY cpownerhashcode instead of where clause.

Comment: @SanuraHettiarachchi My first thought too. But OP want 2 counts one `=0` and one `!=0`

Answer (score 0):

Use union for the resulting tables

```
 (select  statename, count(*)
 from state where stateid = cpownerstate
 and cpownerhashcode=0 
 group by statename)
 union 
 (select  statename, count(*)
 from state where stateid = cpownerstate
 and cpownerhashcod!=0 
 group by statename);
```